# ¿Cómo mostrar icono en cada ítem del menú con recyclerview?

Tags: recyclerview, menú

Quiero mostrar un icono al lado de cada ítem del menú, tanto el menú padre como el menú hijo, estoy usando expandable recyclerview; los iconos están alojados en las carpetas mipmap o drawable; si me pueden ayudar reorganizando los parámetros que reciben los diferentes métodos que hacen esto posible y en MainActivity en el método getGenres() poder agregar el texto y la imagen: itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Portal", R.drawable.ic_launcher));. comparto todo el código ya en los layouts se encuentran los dos ficheros con las etiquetas de texto e imagen. Muchas gracias.

layout padre:
list_categoria.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#6298e2">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_cate_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_cate_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:textColor="#02400b"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Categoria" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_cate_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
```

Layout hijo: list_subcategoria.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#375173">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_scate_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Artist Name" />
```

ViewHolders
MenuCategoriaViewHolder.java

```
public class MenuCategoriaViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

private TextView categoriaTitle;

public MenuCategoriaViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    categoriaTitle =    (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cate_name);
}

public void setCategoriaName(String name){
    categoriaTitle.setText(name);
}
```

}

ViewHolder
ItemMenuViewHolder.java

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

private TextView itemName;

public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
}

public void setItemName(String name){
    itemName.setText(name);
}
```

}

Modelos
MenuCategoria.java

```
public class MenuCategoria extends ExpandableGroup {
public MenuCategoria(String title, List items) {
    super(title, items);
}
```

}

Modelos
ItemMenu.java

```
public class ItemMenu {
private String name;

public ItemMenu(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return name;
}

public void setItemName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Adaptador:
MenuAdapter.java

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder> {

    public MenuAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuCategoriaViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_categoria, parent, false);
        return new MenuCategoriaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);
        return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

        holder.setItemName(itemMenu.getItemName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MenuCategoriaViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        holder.setCategoriaName(group.getTitle());
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//variables recyclerview
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
private List<MenuCategoria> menuCategorias;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //RecyclerView en el navigationDrawer
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    getGenres();
    mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(menuCategorias);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void getGenres() {

    menuCategorias = new ArrayList<>(3);

    List<ItemMenu> itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(5);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Portal"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Biblioteca"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("EduVirtual"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Directorio"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Preguntas"));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Portal", itemMenus));

    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(2);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Siga"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Apoyo a la Presencialidad"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Virtualidad"));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Plataformas", itemMenus));

    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(7);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Facebook"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Twitter"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Linkedin"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Flicker"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Youtube"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Google +"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Instagram"));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Redes Sociales", itemMenus));


}
```

A continuación muestro una imagen de como se encuentra ahora y a la derecha de lo que deseo hacer, cada punto de color correspondería a un icono diferente por cada item en el menu.  Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu elemento `list_subcategoria.xml` ya tiene un elemento `ImageView` que puede usarse para este propósito que es `list_item_cate_icon` por lo tanto en tu clase `MenuCategoriaViewHolder` obtén la referencia:

Obtén la referencia y úsalo como contenedor para el icono:

```
 public class MenuCategoriaViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

    private TextView categoriaTitle;
    private ImageView icono; 

    public MenuCategoriaViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        categoriaTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cate_name);              
        icono = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cate_icon);

    }

    public void setCategoriaName(String name){
        categoriaTitle.setText(name);
    }

    public void setIcono(int idResource){
       icono.setImageResource(idResource);
    }
 }
```

Realiza lo mismo para tus subcategorias.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: te agradezco mucho esta ayuda, llevaba varios días en esto, no tengo experiencia en esto solo estoy tratando de aprender por medio de tutoriales; quiero hacerte una pregunta con respecto a esta pregunta ya pude lograr que salieran los iconos, con tu ayuda claro está, voy a continuar con este ejercicio; la pregunta es: cuando trato de emular con el avd me genera un error y la app se cierra, pero he generado el apk y lo llevo a una carpeta de mi celular y desde allí lo instalo y funciona bien ¿abrá algun problema con android estudio?

Comment: @Alfredo probablemente no tienes definido storage en tu AVD, o no existe conexión a internet, revisa en el LogCat que mensaje se despliega, definitivamente el LogCat determinará fácilmente cual es el problema real. Te aconsejo agregar una pregunta con tu LogCat ! :D

Comment: acabo de agregar una nueva pregunta, dandole continuidad a mi ejercicio, ahora quiero agregar los listener para cambiar entre fragmentos, solo he podido encontrar que con RecyclerView es diferente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110234/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-fragmentos-de-acuerdo-a-los-items-recyclerview

Comment: He subido el proyecto a GitHub no se si le puedas hechar un vistazo https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp